# C++ SFINAE void_t not working

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I tried running following code, which should rely on `void_t` trick, where more specialized class template should be chosen (in this case second one)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class ...>
using void_t = void;

template <class T, class = void>
struct is_incrementable : public std::false_type { };
template <class T>
struct is_incrementable<T, void_t<decltype(++(std::declval<T>()))>> : public std::true_type { };

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_incrementable<int>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am using MSVC 2015. However, the result of `is_incrementable<int>::value` is false. Is there anything wrong with my code or is there problem with my compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::declval<T>` has return type `T&&`, so `std::declval<int>()` is an *rvalue* of type `int`. The result of "false" is telling you that an `int` *rvalue* is not incrementable, which is correct.

You can replace `std::declval<T>` with `std::declval<T&>` to get the program to tell you whether an *lvalue* of type `T` is incrementable. If you make this change to your program, it should print "true".